# Web socket performance

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Can browser cache effect web-socket performance when there is a heavy load socket connection? What is the best way to close a web socket connection and reconnect if required?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you think the browser cache might affect WebSocket performance. Restarting a WebSocket should be easy; you can just listen for the error or close events and then open the socket back up again. I run a WebSocket connection that takes about 2.5k short (i.e. 150b) JSON messages per second without breaking a sweat. Updating the DOM with info from the messages is much slower (to the point that we've had to throttle DOM updates).

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that Browser caches disconnected web socket connections and this cache affects the web socket connection performance? Just wanted to know the *cache* you are referring to? If you are worried about closed or disconnected web socket connections, browser will not cache any web socket connections(closed or disconnected). I guess, cache you are referring is memory or web socket objects.